# Pandas - store numpy array in a dataframe column which is a result of function

Tags: python, pandas, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I have a pandas dataframe with a column `allTexts` which stores a bunch of text information for each row. I am trying to apply a custom function which returns 3 values given the input text. I then want to store these 3 output values in a new dataframe column -  ideally as a numpy array for each row. I do it with `apply()`, the code completes successfully but it doesn't actually change values.

```
#stub for creating a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'allText':['Hateful text. This is bad', 'Text about great stuff', ' ']})

#set a placeholder - just 3 zeros for each record
df['Sentiments'] = df['allText'].apply(lambda x: np.zeros(3))

#function definition. It is a textblob library function, which gives me back sentiment scores for each text
def getTextSentiments(text):
    blob = TextBlob(text)
    pos = 0
    neg = 0
    neutral = 0
    count = 0
    for sentence in blob.sentences:
        sentiment = sentence.sentiment.polarity
        if sentiment > 0.1:
            pos +=1
        elif sentiment > -0.1:
            neutral +=1
        else:
            neg +=1
        count+=1
    if count == 0:
        count = 1
    return numpy.array([pos/count, neutral/count, neg/count])

#apply function only for non-empty texts and override 3 zeros in sentiments column with real 3 values
df[df["allText"]!=" "]['Sentiments'] = df[df["allText"]!=" "]["allText"].apply(getTextSentiments)
```

After this code completes without any error I still end up with same value of all zeros in my Sentiments column.

MVP to demonstrate it doesn't work even with single record:

```
df[df["allText"]!=" "].iloc[0]['Sentiments']
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
test = getTextSentiments(df[df["allText"]!=" "].iloc[0]['allText'])

test
Out[64]: (0.4166666666666667, 0.5, 0.08333333333333333)
df[df["allText"]!=" "].iloc[0]['Sentiments'] = test

df[df["allText"]!=" "].iloc[0]['Sentiments']
Out[75]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Any advice on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @Allen I updated question which creates the dataframe now

Comment: Lines like these `df[df["allText"]!=" "]['Sentiments']`, should look like this `df.loc[df.allText != ‘ ‘,’Sentiments’]`

Comment: @DJK yeah, I tried that too - didn't help. Was failing with error of index mismatch. Luckily the issue is solved now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following?

```
df.Sentiments = df.apply(lambda x: x.Sentiments if x.allText ==' ' else getTextSentiments(x.allText), axis=1)
```

Using a dummy getTextSentiments function for test:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'allText':['Hateful text. This is bad', 'Text about great stuff', ' ']})

#set a placeholder - just 3 zeros for each record
df['Sentiments'] = df['allText'].apply(lambda x: np.zeros(3))
def getTextSentiments(text):
    return (0.4166666666666667, 0.5, 0.08333333333333333)
df.Sentiments = df.apply(lambda x: x.Sentiments if x.allText ==' ' else getTextSentiments(x.allText), axis=1)
df
Out[181]: 
                     allText                                      Sentiments
Out[181]: 
                     allText                                      Sentiments
0  Hateful text. This is bad  (0.4166666666666667, 0.5, 0.08333333333333333)
1     Text about great stuff  (0.4166666666666667, 0.5, 0.08333333333333333)
2                                                            [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: You probably meant df.Sentiments = df.apply(lambda x: x.Sentiments if x.allText ==' ' else getTextSentiments(x.allText), axis=1)

Comment: In any case it says: AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'allText'", 'occurred at index allText')

Comment: @MaximHaytovich, can you run the test code in my answer to see if it works? It worked for me.

Comment: Figured this out - I see why it didn't work. My function was actually returning not tubple by numpy array (updated the question to reflect this). I don't know why your code was failing if it returns a numpy array but using your idea I updated it to work with numpy array too: df['Sentiments'] = df["allText"].apply(lambda x: np.zeros(3) if x == ' ' else getTextSentiments(x))
 Thank you!

Comment: Great it helped.